# Image Data Type Export Different with BCP vs SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, bcp

I have a Stored Procedure process(scheduled SQL Job) created using BCP to export PDF file data from a image datatype to a PDF file on a network share.

Due to a client request, I'm wanting to migrate this process to SSIS.  The SSIS process works, but the pdf generated is different.  I'm trying to wrap my head around why this would be different if the source information (image field) is exactly the same?  I was wondering if it some kind of layering in the original PDF that just isn't getting reproduced using SSIS?

Thanks for any assistance with this.

Correct PDF Format
[image: Correct PDF Format]

Incorrect PDF Format
[image: Incorrect PDF Format]

Comment: I'm wondering if you have "almost" identical images in your stack of data (an older and newer version). SSIS and BCP have been known to import stacks of data at different sections of the data stream to multi-task the import process jumbling the output from the original order of the input. Could this be true for your data?

Comment: Actually as of right now there is very limited data because they just started using this function of the system.  So I'm only dealing with 5 records that have image data (PDF documents).  Basically its enough data to test.

Comment: A pdf can contain layers incl tect and images. (Im surprised youre saving it in an image field). I wonder if 1 tool is treating it correctly as a pdf and the other is only handling the image content of the pdf. What happens if you store them with a different datatype like a blob?